# Remove Permalink of certain posts

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

Is there a way to remove the permalink on specific posts?

Ideally there should be a plugin that makes the permalink optional on some posts.

I know that there is a private option. But this does not fix my issue, some posts are just for embedding purposes but shouldn't be accessible as it's own page.

I would like to fire a 404 instead.

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean specific post types?

Comment: Nope, I meant posts.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect a few posts to 404 page then you can use use the following snippet in functions.php of your child theme.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'post_redirect_func' );
function post_redirect_func(){
    global $post;
    $redirect_url = get_template_part( 404 ); // you can write here the page to redirect if this don't work for you
    if ($post->ID == "IDOFPOST1" || $post->ID == "IDOFPOST2"){ // you can add more id by adding || $post->ID == "IDOFPOST3" before )
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url, 302 );
        exit;
    }
}
```